# Getting the local port number of a socket

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

In vanilla .net, the `Socket` class has a property `LocalEndPoint` which provides details of the local end of the socket, including the port. In the Windows Phone 7 `Socket`, this property is missing.

Is there any way of getting the port number of the local end of a socket?

**Update**

I'm implementing a simple network protocol on WP7. The server it will be working with uses callbacks and the original request query must specify the port for the callback to be sent to (The server API does not have support for accessing details of the incoming connection, and changing this part of the code is not an option at this point). Both phone and server connect to each other over a local network.

Comment: It may be useful to explain what your use case is that needs it, to help offer solutions -- you need to be aware that some devices will be hidden behind big NAT firewalls, so the IP/port that the phone thinks it has may well differ to what the outside world thinks.

Comment: @RowlandShaw I've updated the question to explain our use case briefly

Comment: Could you not use push notifications instead?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I'm afraid not, rewriting the server side of things is not an option at the moment. The requirements are that this has to be done through the protocol, which uses UDP only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer at the moment appears to be "No".

If anyone knows why Microsoft don't want you to know this, please let me know.